# crontab conflict: set run times and execution times conflict

Tags: linux, cron

Lets say I have a crontab job that runs every minute, and the job involves mailing the output of a shell script to some email address. I know for sure that this job takes more than a minute to complete. How does the operating system handle this? I check my syslog, it shows me that the job is running, but no indication of an email being sent. I am relatively new to Linux, so bear with me please :]

Comment: Great question. There's always this issue when considering "a job runs every X seconds" and the job takes a considerable amount of time respect to X. I'm downloading the cron source code to see what it does.
__EDIT__: It appears that in this case the job would be run multiple times. When cron needs to run a job it forks to execute that job and continues its normal operation. I'll try to reproduce this and post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=/tmp/test$RANDOM

touch "$file"
sleep 600
rm "$file"
```

And running it every minute in my crontab.

```
guido@solid:~$ crontab -l
*   *   *   *   *   /home/guido/cmd.sh
```

I can see that there are many instances of cmd.sh running by:

```
guido@solid:~$ ls /tmp/test*
/tmp/test7822   /tmp/test12278  /tmp/test16118  /tmp/test25642
/tmp/test11429  /tmp/test15958  /tmp/test18172  /tmp/test26104
guido@solid:~$ ps -e |grep cmd.sh
26005 ?        00:00:00 cmd.sh
26454 ?        00:00:00 cmd.sh
26999 ?        00:00:00 cmd.sh
27450 ?        00:00:00 cmd.sh
27895 ?        00:00:00 cmd.sh
28667 ?        00:00:00 cmd.sh
29220 ?        00:00:00 cmd.sh
29727 ?        00:00:00 cmd.sh
30232 ?        00:00:00 cmd.sh
```

This means, your mailing job is being ran multiple times, which may lead to some problems. Either up the interval until you're sure that there's no *overlap*, or change the job to take a *lock* so there are no issues.

As to why there's no indication on your mail being sent, I can't help without more info.

Comment: thank you for your time and the ps command, and yes, i modified my interval. i think the mail not going is a MTA installation issue, so will look into that. Cheers :]